# Having problems on getting actual time in UTC Android

Tags: java, android, datetime, utc

I am trying to get the the day and time in UTC as milliseconds but repeatedly get the same problem. The result should be something like '63530139420000' but each time the value '1394547490884' is returned.

To get the date and time in UTC I use the following method:

```
long dateutc = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Hard to see how you're getting the same value every time. Also, how do you know what the result should be?  That latter number looks far more like the current time than the former. Take that latter number and convert it into day/month/year, then do the same with the former.

Comment: I said it wrongly. I don´t get the same value, but each time I execute obviously it increases but my teacher told me that the correct time should be something like '63530139420000' that is much higher than the value I get. Is it correct the mehtod I use?

Comment: You're getting the time the correct way, and your expectations for what the number should look like are wrong.   I can't explain why your teacher thinks the number should look that way, because it doesn't. I guess it might do some time in the future...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this.

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String dateutc = df.format(new Date());
```

Comment: When I put that code it shows the following error: "The method getTimeInstance() is undefined for the type DateFormat". How I can solve it?

Comment: use java.util.date probably you use other Date

Comment: You have to import DateFormat as **import java.text.DateFormat;**

Comment: when I put this code it shows me the actual time but how I convert it to UTC?

Comment: Now check my answer now.

Comment: I am sorry, I confused what I want. I want the time in milliseconds but I get a wrong value (said by my teacher). Do you know how to convert it to milliseconds? Sorry for the inconvinience

Comment: Sorry again but I am very confused because of this. So this is the true request I am searching: Get in milliseconds the UTC datetime. Do you know how to convert the date you have put in milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

Your code correctly gets the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Interestingly if you take the value your teacher has specified and divide by the number of milliseconds in a year you get 2014.5. So either your teacher doesn't know what currentTimeMillis() does or he wants milliseconds since year 0 (which doesn't make any sense to me).

To calculate number of milliseconds since a given date all you need to do is to create two date instances and subtract the milliseconds values from getTime().

Comment: I think he may want the milliseconds since year (I suppose). If this is the case, how I get it?